# how to push the data from a select in a single array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select, my api expects that i send an array of strings like this **["purple", "red", "orange"]** but react-select gives me an array of objects, so what I did was map throught newValue picking each value and putting in an vaiable array, but i'm getting each value in separated arrays like this **["purple"], ["red"], ["orange"]**

```
handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
console.log("newValue-->",newValue);
newValue.map((obj: any) => {
  const array = [];
  array.push(obj.value);
  console.log("array-->",array);
});
```

[image]

complete code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-sf7tz?file=/example.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your array outside before map.

Otherwise you are creating new array for each object.

```
 const array = [];
 newValue.map((obj: any) => {  
  array.push(obj.value);
  console.log("array-->",array);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [react select](https://react-select.com/home) docs, it should be an array of objects with value and label. so in your case you can do in the below way.

```js
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

let input = ["purple", "red", "orange"] 

let output = input.map(item => ({value: item, label: capitalizeFirstLetter(item) }))

console.log(output)
```

Explanation on the Question snippet

```
newValue.map((obj: any) => {
  const array = [];
  array.push(obj.value);
  console.log("array-->",array);
});
```

Here you are mapping through each object, then every time mapping you are creating an empty array, to that array you push the value and print it.

So take first item as example, red iterates -> empty array created -> push the red value to empty array and then printing it.

So this loops three times since the length of the array is 3, so three times you get the array.

Fix on the question snippet is declare the array outside the loop and push in the same manner as the doc suggest then you can pass to react select component as options props and it will work as expected.